# Динамическое обновление таблицы QtableWidget в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtimer

В главном окне `MainWindow` создается таблица `self.tableWidget`, в которую поступают данные из класса `DataParser` (в данном примере этот класс явно не использован, примером данных, отправляемых этим классом является список `list_to_add`).

Данные вида `list_to_add` могут приходить в любое время. 
При получении данных необходимо добавить новую запись в таблицу. 
Для имеющихся записей нужно каждую секунду вычитать из текущей даты и времени, дату и время в `list_to_add`, соответствующих каждой записи и динамически обновлять значения в таблице в соотв. с результатом.

Пример:

```
list_to_add = ['2021-02-02 09:00:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START'] #[operation date, operation name, status]
```

При получении такого списка, создаем новую строку, создаем ячейку, в которой храним разность текущей даты и времени и `'2021-02-02 09:00:00'`, каждую секунду обновляем эту ячейку.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Override class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # You must call the super class method
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))         # Set sizes
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")    # Set the window title
        central_widget = QWidget(self)              # Create a central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)       # Install the central widget

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)         # Create QGridLayout
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)   # Set this layout in central widget

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)  # Create a table
        header_font = QFont('Sergoe UI', 12)
        header_font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([ "Относительное время","Абсолютное время", "Название операции"])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 250)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 250)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 250)

        list_to_add = ['2021-02-02 09:00:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START'] #[operation date, operation name, status]

        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()

        date_now = datetime.now()
        datetime_event = datetime.strptime(list_to_add[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        delta_sec = (datetime.now() - datetime_event).total_seconds()
        time_abs = self.convert_sec_to_time(delta_sec)

        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(list_to_add[1]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))

        #grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)   # Adding the table to the grid

    def convert_sec_to_time(self, seconds) -> str:

        hours, remainder = divmod(seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

        return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите обновлять и какими данными вы хотите обновлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того что я понял, для обнавления данных вам надо хранить `'2021-02-02 09:00:00'`
и я это сделал сохраняя эти данные в колонку с индексом **3**.

Вы можете не показывать ее в таблице, применив строку:

```
self.tableWidget.setColumnHidden(3, True)
```

Я реализовал обновление данных после каждого добавления новой строки.
Если вам все же надо обновляться каждую секунду (?),
то необходимо реализовать повторяющиеся `QTimer` и
каждую секунду выполнять:

```
    # обновляем значения в таблице
    rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
   
    for row in range(rows):                    
        _data = self.tableWidget.item(row, 3).text()
        time_abs = self.time_abs_func([_data,])
        # обратите внимание, что я вставляю обновленные данные               !!!
        # в колонку с индексом 0 (ноль) - чтобы вы видели, что происходит    !!!
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
#        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
```

Я прокомментировал для вас свой пример, попробуйте:

---

```
import sys
import random                                                                   # +++
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class DataParser(QThread):
    data_signal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super(DataParser, self).__init__()
        self._date = ''
        self._nameProg = ''
        self._start = ''
        self._flag = True

    def run(self):
        self.msleep(2000)
        # вставьте в этот цикл свою логику получения списка list_to_add
        # у меня это рандомный _list, который формируется каждые 10 секунд,
        # чтобы вы спокойно могли наблюдать что происходит
        while(self._flag):
            #             '2021-02-02 09:00:00' обратите внимание я поменял дату
            self._date = f'2021-02-03 {random.randrange(0, 24):0>2}:'\
                          f'{random.randrange(0, 60):0>2}:'\
                          f'{random.randrange(0, 60):0>2}'
            self._nameProg = f'PROGRAM {random.randrange(1,99):0>2}'
            self._start = 'Что-то еще?'
                          
            _list = [self._date, self._nameProg, self._start]
            self.data_signal.emit(_list)                  # отдаем список в основной поток
            self.msleep(10000)                                            # спим 10 секунд


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 100))
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)       
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)         # - self  --> + central_widget !!!
#        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)            # --- нет

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)  
        header_font = QFont('Sergoe UI', 12)
        header_font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)                #(3) обратите внимание я добавил столбец 

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            [ "Относительное время","Абсолютное время", "Название операции"]
        )
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 190)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 180)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 180)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 180)     # обратите внимание я добавил столбец 

# ВНИМАНИЕ !!! раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы Скрыть столбец с индексом 3       !!!      
#        self.tableWidget.setColumnHidden(3, True)   # Скрыть столбец с индексом 3  !!!

#        list_to_add = ['2021-02-03 09:00:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START'] # обратите внимание я поменял дату
        list_to_add = ['2021-02-03 17:20:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START']  # !!!

        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        time_abs = self.time_abs_func(list_to_add)
#-        print(f'time_abs = {time_abs}')

        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(list_to_add[1]))
        # обратите внимание я добавил столбец vvv                               !!!
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 3, QTableWidgetItem(list_to_add[0]))   
        
        #grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)                   # Adding the table to the grid
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0)         # +++ !!!
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.thread = DataParser()
        self.thread.data_signal.connect(self.update_data)
        self.thread.start()

    def time_abs_func(self, list_to_add):
        date_now = datetime.now()
        datetime_event = datetime.strptime(list_to_add[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        delta_sec = (datetime.now() - datetime_event).total_seconds()
        return self.convert_sec_to_time(delta_sec)

    def convert_sec_to_time(self, seconds) -> str:
        hours, remainder = divmod(seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
    
    def update_data(self, _data):
        """ Тут мы добавляем новую запись в таблицу 
            и динамически обновляем значения в таблице.
            _data - это полученный из класса DataParser - list_to_add
        """
        time_abs = self.time_abs_func(_data)
        
#        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()         # добавить в конец
        rowPos = 0                                    # добавить в начало 
        
        # добавляем новую запись
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(_data[1])) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 3, QTableWidgetItem(_data[0])) # !!!


        # обновляем значения в таблице
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
       
#        for row in range(0, rows-1):                 # для rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()     
        for row in range(1, rows):                    # для rowPos = 0
            _data = self.tableWidget.item(row, 3).text()
            time_abs = self.time_abs_func([_data,])
            # обратите внимание, что я вставляю обновленные данные               !!!
            # в колонку с индексом 0 (ноль) - чтобы вы видели, что происходит    !!!
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
#            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(810, 500)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы уже имеющиеся записи в разделе "абсолютное время" обновлялись каждую секунду? Для этого тоже надо создавать отдельный тред?

Обратите внимание на строки помеченные `# *** QTimer`

```
import sys
import random                                                                   # +++
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QTimer                 # *** QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class DataParser(QThread):
    data_signal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super(DataParser, self).__init__()
        self._date = ''
        self._nameProg = ''
        self._start = ''
        self._flag = True

    def run(self):
        self.msleep(2000)
        # вставьте в этот цикл свою логику получения списка list_to_add
        # у меня это рандомный _list, который формируется каждые 5 секунд,
        # чтобы вы спокойно могли наблюдать что происходит
        while(self._flag):
            #             '2021-02-02 09:00:00' обратите внимание я поменял дату
            self._date = f'2021-02-03 {random.randrange(0, 24):0>2}:'\
                          f'{random.randrange(0, 60):0>2}:'\
                          f'{random.randrange(0, 60):0>2}'
            self._nameProg = f'PROGRAM {random.randrange(1,99):0>2}'
            self._start = 'Что-то еще?'
                          
            _list = [self._date, self._nameProg, self._start]
            self.data_signal.emit(_list)                  # отдаем список в основной поток
            self.msleep(5000)                                            # спим 5 секунд    !!!


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 100))
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)       
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)         # - self  --> + central_widget !!!
#        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)            # --- нет

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)  
        header_font = QFont('Sergoe UI', 12)
        header_font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)                #(3) обратите внимание я добавил столбец 

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            [ "Относительное время","Абсолютное время", "Название операции"]
        )
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setFont(header_font)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 190)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 180)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 180)     # 250
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 180)     # обратите внимание я добавил столбец 

# ВНИМАНИЕ !!! раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы Скрыть столбец с индексом 3       !!!      
        self.tableWidget.setColumnHidden(3, True)   # Скрыть столбец с индексом 3  !!!

#        list_to_add = ['2021-02-03 09:00:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START'] # обратите внимание я поменял дату
        list_to_add = ['2021-02-03 17:20:00', 'PROGRAM', 'START']  # !!!

        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        time_abs = self.time_abs_func(list_to_add)
#-        print(f'time_abs = {time_abs}')

        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(list_to_add[1]))
        # обратите внимание я добавил столбец vvv                               !!!
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 3, QTableWidgetItem(list_to_add[0]))   
        
        #grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)                   # Adding the table to the grid
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0)         # +++ !!!
        
        self.thread = DataParser()
        self.thread.data_signal.connect(self.update_data)
        self.thread.start()
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.updateTime)   # *** QTimer
        self.timer.start()                                                  # *** QTimer

    def updateTime(self):                                                   # *** QTimer
        # обновляем значения в таблице
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):                    
            _data = self.tableWidget.item(row, 3).text()
            time_abs = self.time_abs_func([_data,])
            # обратите внимание, что я вставляю обновленные данные               !!!
            # в колонку с индексом 0 (ноль) - чтобы вы видели, что происходит    !!!
#            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs)) 

    def time_abs_func(self, list_to_add):
        date_now = datetime.now()
        datetime_event = datetime.strptime(list_to_add[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        delta_sec = (datetime.now() - datetime_event).total_seconds()
        return self.convert_sec_to_time(delta_sec)

    def convert_sec_to_time(self, seconds) -> str:
        hours, remainder = divmod(seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
    
    def update_data(self, _data):
        """ Тут мы добавляем новую запись в таблицу 
            и динамически обновляем значения в таблице.
            _data - это полученный из класса DataParser - list_to_add
        """
        time_abs = self.time_abs_func(_data)
        
#        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()         # добавить в конец
        rowPos = 0                                    # добавить в начало 
        
        # добавляем новую запись
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(_data[1])) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 3, QTableWidgetItem(_data[0]))  # !!!

'''
        # обновляем значения в таблице
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
       
#        for row in range(0, rows-1):                 # для rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()     
        for row in range(1, rows):                    # для rowPos = 0
            _data = self.tableWidget.item(row, 3).text()
            time_abs = self.time_abs_func([_data,])
            # обратите внимание, что я вставляю обновленные данные               !!!
            # в колонку с индексом 0 (ноль) - чтобы вы видели, что происходит    !!!
#            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(time_abs))        
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(810, 500)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы уже имеющиеся записи в разделе "абсолютное время" обновлялись каждую секунду? Для этого тоже надо создавать отдельный тред?

Comment: Можно ли функцию update_data поместить в тред?

Comment: @follow_the_sun  не совсем понимаю куда вы хотите поместить метод `update_data`. Задайте новый вопрос, приведите приме того, что и куда вы хотите поместить и для чего вы хотите это сделать, а также  расскажите, что у вас не получается.